# Locale country Android ISO

Tags: java, android

What give you this in return

```
getSimCountryIso()
```

Returns for USA for example  "USA" "US" or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> public String getSimCountryIso()
>
> Since: API Level 1
>   Returns the **ISO country code** equivalent for the SIM
>   provider's country code.

*[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso%28%29)*

[ISO Country Codes](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html)

Comment: Uh sorry, missed your question completely there. These are the 2 letter ones in my experience, but I can't find any doc stating that this has to be it. Just run the function on a phone and see what you get (you can also run `adb shell` to get a shell on your phone and then `getprop gsm.sim.operator.iso-country`). In my case I get "DE" for Germany. The output has to be consistent at least.